# Jquery append not loading javascript for element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I'm making an endless scroll table with movie details and at the movie storyline I have an easy more/less javascript function(when you click more,it displays all text and when you click less it hides it back) in order to make the table look nice.
The problem is that after the first 10 movies when the endless scroll kicks in the more/less function doesn't work for the rest of the movies and it displays the entire story line.

The endless scroll script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $('div#loadingModal').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "movies.php?lastMovie=" + $(".postedMovies:last").attr('id'),
                success: function (html) {
                    $('div#loadingModal').hide();
                    if (html) {
                        $("#postedMovies").append(html);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

More or less method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function () {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if (content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
```

});

Php echo

```
echo "<tr class='postedMovies' id=\" $fuid \">";

echo'    

            <td>'.$_SESSION['fid'].'</td>
            <td><img width="51px" height="72px"   src="'.$movie_posterlarge.'" /></td>
            <td><a target="_blank" href="'.$movie_url.'">'.$movie_title.'</a></td>
            <td>'.$movie_released.'</td>
            <td>'.$movie_genres.'</td>
            <td>'.$movie_rating_imdb.'</td>
            <td>'.$movie_rating_user.'</td>
            <td width="200 px">'.$movie_viewed.'</td>
            <td style="text-align:left"><div class="comment more">'.$movie_storyline.'</div></td>


        ';

echo "</tr>";
```

This is the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ftb4e.png

Comment: please post your `more` and `less` method. and html too

Comment: did you check your serve code? what you are sending or what you are receiving?

Comment: You mean after loading 10 click on more/less links does not do anything?

Comment: The first ten links are loaded when the page loads.The next ones are loaded after the user scrolls down and they don't display the show more/less link.

Comment: yes, because you have to call `$('.more').each(...` after every load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to add `more` links to new elements after every ajax call. And use `jQuery.on` to add click listener which will take care of newly added elements.

Hope this will help -

```
var showChar = 100;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";

function addMoreLink($elements) {
    $elements.each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
        if (content.length > showChar) {
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar - 1, content.length - showChar);
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext + '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h
                    + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

            $(this).html(html);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            $('div#loadingModal').show();
            $.ajax({
                url : "movies.php?lastMovie=" + $(".postedMovies:last").attr('id'),
                success : function(html) {
                    $('div#loadingModal').hide();
                    if (html) {
                        var newElements = $(html);
                        $("#postedMovies").append(newElements);
                        addMoreLink(newElements.find('.more'));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    addMoreLink($('.more'));

    /* using jquery on, will take care of newly added elements */
    $("table").on("click", ".morelink", function(event) {
        if ($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!I've been battling this problem for a few days and you solved it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType`:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {    
            $('div#loadingModal').show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "movies.php?lastMovie="+ $(".postedMovies:last").attr('id'),
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function(html) {
                    $('div#loadingModal').hide();
                    if(html){       
                        $("#postedMovies").append(html);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Or else, depending on exactly what you're getting back, jQueryify the html data:

```
$("#postedMovies").append($(html))
```

Comment: That is not an answer.

Comment: Perhaps not, but I'll leave it in case it helps someone else with a similar question.